# PyGTK: Embed a window into another window

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to embed a window into another window, kind of like this:
EDIT: Screenshots deleted, sorry!
That is a wingdows program and was not made with GTK tough.
I tried using plugs and sockets, but apparently I can't put a gtk.Window (a toplevel window) on a plug.

Is it possible? If so, how? If not, what do you think I should do instead?

Answer (score 2):

`gtk.Window` is derived from `gtk.Bin`, so it can only contain one single child. This again can be used in the following way:

- Load both windows (e.g. from Glade files)
- Remove the child from the second window, but save a reference to the child
- Add the child somewhere in the first window

The second step would look like this:

```
childWidget = secondWindow.get_child()
secondWindow.remove(childWidget)
```

I'm using this approach to add plugin windows as tabs in one of my PyGTK applications. That means main window and plugins can be designed separately in Glade, and also implemented independently. Of course you're free to add the child widget anywhere you want.

Comment: @Gerardo: Then probably I didn't understand your question correctly. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a "sub window" inside a "main window", and be able to move the sub window and all, but always within the boundaries of the main window. Did you see the screenshots?

Comment: @Gerardo: Oh, you mean something like a MDI. I don't think such a window-in-window interface is supported in GTK+. My answer gives you a way to "pin" the window contents somewhere, and you can simply create a new window with that child widget if you want to unpin it again.

Comment: Oh, so THAT's how it's called, huh?  Well, thank you very much for your time and effort. I'll see what to do.